# StageWebView issue on ipad

Tags: ipad, webview

I am using stageWebView for showing webpage in my mobile app but don't know how to move back to my app once it gets loaded. In application descriptor file, I had already registered custom uri scheme (myapp://) for IOS devices and from the loaded page inside stageWebView, I was trying to call following URL myapp://webcam. But nothing had happened. It neither called LOCATION_CHANGE event of StageWebView not called INVOKE_EVENT of nativeapplication.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Mamta

Answer (score 1):

Custom URIs don't work in StageWebView ([adobe help page)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html)

Instead of a custom URI, use a hash tag and listen for Event.COMPLETE events on the StageWebView.

```
<a href="#webcam">Webcam</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="myapp://webcam">Webcam</a>
```

You'll get a Event.COMPLETE event when they click the link and can then check the StageWebView.location for a location hash.